# How to extract XML string from parquet column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My spark streaming job decompresses a compressed XML file and appends it as string to parquet File.
My batch job reads parquet file. This file contains only one column decompressed xml string.

Parquet file schema:

```
DF.printSchema()
```

> root
>   |-- decompressed: string (nullable = true)

Sample record in parquet file

```
DF.show(1,False)

|decompress                                                           
------------------------------------------------+ 
|<Sale><ItemID >10</ItemID>......</Sale>
```

Is there any way I can apply data bricks XML package on it to extract xml elements. Do I have any other option other than writing UDF? I am keeping UDF as second option, considering UDF's take more time to process.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply databricks `spark-xml` package only on files (not on RDD/DF). The only option here is to save your DF under some temporary path as text files using `DF.write.text()` and read newly saved files.

But here comes a question - why do you save XMLs as one-column parquet files in your spark streaming job? Why not plan text files, readable by `spark-xml` package?

Comment: Thank you, Marius. My streaming job has to extract specific columns from compressed XML for realtime reporting purpose. My batch job has to prepare data for downstream systems. My batch job runs once a day. In streaming job, I am trying to decompress XML file, extract columns needed for reporting, prepare data for batch processing(Batch job needs full XML contents). For batch process I don't want to have thousands of very small files, for that purpose I am trying to append to a file, instead of having each stream in a separate file.

Comment: AFAIK, even if you append to parquet dataset (in streaming job), small files are created in a directory. In spark you cannot easily append to parquet file, see [SPARK-18199](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18199). If you change writing method to raw text files, it will allow you to read them directly in batch job.